# Existence of an orthogonal linear operator $T$ on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations, orthogonality

> Let $r\le n$ be natural numbers and let $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_r\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots ,w_r\}$ be two linearly independent subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\langle w_i,w_j\rangle\forall 1\le i,j\le r$ where $\langle \rangle $ denotes standard inner product on $\Bbb R^n$
>
> Show that there exists an orthogonal linear operator $T$ on $\Bbb R^n$ such that $Tv_i=w_i\forall 1\le i\le r.$

**ATTEMPT**:

*Please tell me if my answer is right or wrong*.

> Both the sets $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_r\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots ,w_r\}$  can be extended to a  basis of $\Bbb R^{n}$  such that $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_r,v_{r+1},v_{r+2},\ldots ,v_{n}\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots w_r,w_{r+1},w_{r+2},\ldots ,w_{n}\}$ are bases of $\Bbb R^{n}$.

Now define $v^{'}_{r+1}=v_{r+1}-\sum _{i=1}^r\dfrac{\langle v_{r+1},v_i\rangle}{\langle v_i,v_i\rangle } v_i $

and similarly we define

$w^{'}_{r+1}=w_{r+1}-\sum _{i=1}^r\dfrac{\langle w_{r+1},w_i\rangle}{\langle w_i,w_i\rangle } w_i $

> i.e. applying Gram-Schmidt's Process to form $\{v_{r+1},v_{r+2},\ldots ,v_n\} $ such that $||v_{r+1}||=1; \langle v_{r+1},v_i\rangle =0\forall 1\le i\le r$
>
> and similarly we do it for $\{w_{r+1},\ldots,w_n\}$
>
> > We can define a linear transform $T:V\to V$ by $T(v_i)=w_i\forall 1\le i,j\le n$
>
> Now for any $x=\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i$ we have $Tx=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i w_i$.
>   Then $||Tx||=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle =\langle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i w_i,\sum_{i=1}^n c_i w_i\rangle$
>
> > Using the fact that $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle=\langle w_i,w_j\rangle$ and $||v_{r+1}||=1; \langle v_{r+1},v_i\rangle =0\forall 1\le i\le r$
> >      and $||w_{r+1}||=1; \langle w_{r+1},w_i\rangle =0\forall 1\le i\le r$
>
> we have $||Tx||=||x||\forall x$ and $Tv_i=w_i$

**Is the solution correct ?Please suggest edits where required**

Please help me out.

Comment: Are you given that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\langle w_i,w_j\rangle$?  If so, you're doing too much work ($T$ is just a change of basis).

Comment: You should add "orthogonal" in the question for good response

Comment: @MichaelBurr; please check now; I forgot to add "orthogonal " before